# Haskell performance tuning

Tags: performance, haskell

I'm quite new to Haskell, and to learn it better I started solving problems here and there and I ended up with this ([project Euler 34](https://projecteuler.net/problem=34)).

> 145 is a curious number, as 1! + 4! + 5! = 1 + 24 + 120 = 145.
>
> Find the sum of all numbers which are equal to the sum of the factorial >of their digits.
>
> Note: as 1! = 1 and 2! = 2 are not sums they are not included.

I wrote a C and an Haskell brute force solution.

Could someone explain me the Haskell version is ~15x (~0.450 s vs ~6.5s )slower than the C implementation and how to possibly tune and speedup the Haskell solution?

```
unsigned int solve(){
unsigned int result = 0;
unsigned int i=10;
while(i<2540161){
    unsigned int sumOfFacts = 0;
    unsigned int number = i;
    while (number > 0) {
       unsigned int d = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        sumOfFacts += factorial(d);
    }
    
    if (sumOfFacts == i)
        result += i;
    
    i++;
 }
 return result;
}
```

here the haskell solution

```
--BRUTE FORCE SOLUTION
solve:: Int
solve = sum (filter (\x-> sfc x 0 == x) [10..2540160])

--sum factorial of digits
sfc :: Int -> Int -> Int
sfc 0 acc = acc
sfc n acc = sfc n' (acc+fc r)
    where
        n' = div n 10
        r  = mod n 10   --n-(10*n')
        fc 0 =1
        fc 1 =1
        fc 2 =2
        fc 3 =6
        fc 4 =24
        fc 5 =120
        fc 6 =720
        fc 7 =5040
        fc 8 =40320
        fc 9 =362880
```

Comment: Did you compile the Haskell version with `-O`?

Comment: a very similar program compiled with `-O2` runs in 0.55s on my computer

Comment: basically the same with your version (0.54s)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, compile with optimizations. With `ghc-7.10.1 -O2 -fllvm`, the Haskell version runs in **0.54** secs for me. This is already pretty good.

If we want to do even better, we should first replace `div` with `quot` and `mod` with `rem`. `div` and `mod` do some extra work, because they handle the rounding of negative numbers differently. Since we only have positive numbers here, we should switch to the faster functions.

Second, we should replace the pattern matching in `fc` with an array lookup. GHC uses a branching construct for `Int` patterns, and uses binary search when the number of cases is large enough. We can do better here with a lookup.

The new code looks like this:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V

facs :: V.Vector Int
facs =
  V.fromList [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880]

--BRUTE FORCE SOLUTION
solve:: Int
solve = sum (filter (\x-> sfc x 0 == x) [10..2540160])

--sum factorial of digits
sfc :: Int -> Int -> Int
sfc 0 acc = acc
sfc n acc = sfc n' (acc + V.unsafeIndex facs r)
    where
        (n', r) = quotRem n 10

main = print solve
```

It runs in **0.095** seconds on my computer.

Comment: „GHC uses a branching construct for patterns“ – correct, but not for GHC HEAD, where it now uses a jump table: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10137

Comment: You should call `quotRem` instead of `quot` and `rem`.

Comment: @Stefan I guess I could but it doesn't matter at this level of optimization.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner that's really neat!

Comment: @AndrásKovács great answer! I should have tried with compiler optimizations! Anyway your solution on my laptop (quite old Intel centrino) ghc 7.8.2 runs in 555ms (~100 ms slower than mine version) and using the optimization suggested by@stefan speedups at ~350. I will try (and update the question) on my workstation.  Is someone aware of the type of optimizations that come in play using -O2 in this context?

Comment: @Stefan OK I should stick to `quotRem`, because with LLVM it doesn't matter but it does with native codegen.

Comment: @user1417063: it seems you don't have LLVM. GHC 7.8.x works with LLVM 3.4, while GHC 7.10.1 works with LLVM 3.5. If you install it, you can compile with the `-fllvm` flag (LLVM provides a more advanced code generator backend than the default one in GHC). Although even if you use LLVM, GHC 7.8.x can be slower than GHC 7.10.

Comment: @AndrásKovács That's surprising. I expected that the compiler notices this during optimization (even without LLVM). Thanks for the follow-up.